# What is the difference between `C-i` and `<C-i>`?

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, keyboard-macros

I've just set

```
(define-key input-decode-map "\C-i" [\C-i])
(define-key input-decode-map "\C-m" [\C-m])
(define-key input-decode-map "\C-[" [\C-\[])
```

in my config, but I noticed that `C-i` is now remapped to `<C-i>`.

Where is the difference? It's possible to obtain only `C-i`?

I'm interested in getting a `C-i` not a `\t` or a `<C-i>`

Comment: Perhaps you meant `[?\C-i]`, aka `(control ?i)`?

Comment: I also don't know the difference between `"\C-i"` and `"?\C-i"`

Comment: Spontaneously, I don't understand the purpose of the lines. They seem to map some keys to themselves, why do you need them?

Comment: Because in ASCII `C-i` is a `\t`, `C-m` a `\r` and `C-[` an `ESC`

Comment: @Fólkvangr so my original settings was correct?

Comment: @Fólkvangr: I think you're right but I think you should point it out in an answer, rather than change the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm interested in getting a `C-i` not a `\t`

`C-i` and `\t` are the same thing (ASCII character 9; aka `TAB`).

If you want the <kbd>TAB</kbd> *key* to be different to <kbd>C-i</kbd> you can achieve that in a GUI environment (but not in a terminal, where they are, again, the same thing).

In GUI environments, the event `<tab>` is sent to Emacs when the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key is used.

`function-key-map` maps `<tab>` to `TAB` (aka `C-i`, aka `9`) so that in a GUI environment the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key will have the same effect in Emacs that it has in a terminal.

```
(lookup-key function-key-map (kbd "<tab>"))
[9]
```

This translation takes place only if no binding for the `<tab>` event itself was found; so if you do bind something to `<tab>` it will take precedence over any `TAB` bindings. *Normally*<sup>1</sup> there are no bindings for `<tab>`, though, and so the translation tends to take place.

If you want to prevent the translation entirely, you'll need to disable that `function-key-map` binding:

```
(define-key function-key-map (kbd "<tab>") nil)
```

This would completely separate `<tab>` from `C-i` in a GUI environment.

<sup>1</sup> Note that most commands with a tab binding will be using the terminal-friendly value, so expect some things to stop working in a GUI environment if you remove that translation.  You would need to either use `C-i` to invoke those commands, or else add custom bindings for `<tab>` to replicate them.